# Get primary key from query in Ecto

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I want dynamically getting a primary key from query. I have one idea. First, i'm get schema from query (i don't known, how). After, i'm get table name from schema:

```
{_, table_name} = %Core.Schema{}.__meta__.source
```

And send SQL, which the will be getting primary key.
So, three questions are born:

1. Is there a way to get schema from query (and after getting table name)
2. Get table name directly from query?
3. Ecto.primary_key() dont't work with queries, maybe they have other methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the query was built with a schema module (i.e. `from(p in Post)`, not `from(p in "posts")`), you can get the module back using the query's `from` field:

```
iex(1)> query = from(p in Post, where: p.id == 1)
#Ecto.Query<from p in MyApp.Post, where: p.id == 1>
iex(2)> %{from: {_table, module}} = query
#Ecto.Query<from p in MyApp.Post, where: p.id == 1>
iex(3)> module
MyApp.Post
```

To get the primary key defined in the module's schema, you can call `.__schema__(:primary_key)` on the module:

```
iex(4)> module.__schema__(:primary_key)
[:id]
```